# Using a different php script to get wp_loggedin value and then returning value in Android app

Tags: php, android, wordpress

Hello I'm working on a website on WordPress alongside with it's Android app. Can we use a php script in which we can get the user login status (wp_loggedin) and return the value in the Android app?

Comment: Just create a PHP file in your Wordpress theme and output whatever you want and call the URL directly from your Android App.

Comment: Can you provide an example?

Comment: Please find the example as answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to see it as an Ajax call.

Create a PHP file in your theme.

**example.php**

```
if (is_user_logged_in() == true) {
    echo 'true';
}
else {
    echo 'false';
}
```

From your Android app just call the URL *http://example.com/wp-content/YOUR-THEME/example.php*

If the page gives you **true**, that means the user is logged in. If it returns **false**, the user is not logged in.